# Algorithm for finding strings that a specific Regex will match

Tags: c#, regex

Given a regex pattern, I'm trying to find a string that matches it. Similar to how Django reverses them, but in C#. Are there any pre-made C# libraries that do this?

---

**Edit:** Moving this project to [Google code](http://code.google.com/p/revex/) pretty soon.

### Current Test Results

```
^abc$                     > abc                  : pass
\Aa                       > a                    : pass
z\Z                       > z                    : pass
z\z                       > z                    : pass
z\z                       > z                    : pass
\G\(a\)                   > \(a\)                : pass
ab\b                      > ab                   : pass
a\Bb                      > ab                   : pass
\a                        >                     : pass
[\b]                      >                    : pass
\t                        > \t                   : pass
\r                        > \r                   : pass
\v                        > ♂                    : pass
\f                        > \f                   : pass
\n                        > \n                   : pass
\e                        > ←                    : pass
\141                      > a                    : pass
\x61                      > a                    : pass
\cC                       > ♥                    : pass
\u0061                    > a                    : pass
\\                        > \\                   : pass
[abc]                     > a                    : pass
[^abc]                    > î                    : pass
[a-z]                     > a                    : pass
.                         > p                    : pass
\w                        > W                    : pass
\W                        > ☻                    : pass
\s                        > \n                   : pass
\S                        > b                    : pass
\d                        > 4                    : pass
\D                        > G                    : pass
(a)\1                     > aa                   : pass
(?<n>a)\k<n>              > aa                   : pass
(?<n>a)\1                 > aa                   : pass
(a)(?<n>b)\1\2            > abab                 : pass
(?<n>a)(b)\1\2            > abba                 : pass
(a(b))\1\2                > ababb                : pass
(a(b)(c(d)))\1\2\3\4      > abcdabcdbcdd         : pass
a\0                       > a                    : pass
ab*                       > a                    : pass
ab+                       > abbb                 : pass
ab?                       > a                    : pass
ab{2}                     > abb                  : pass
ab{2,}                    > abbbbbbbbb           : pass
ab{2,3}                   > abb                  : pass
ab*?                      > abb                  : pass
ab+?                      > abbbbb               : pass
ab??                      > a                    : pass
ab{2}?                    > abb                  : pass
ab{2,}?                   > abbbbbbbbb           : pass
ab{2,3}?                  > abbb                 : pass
/users(?:/(?<id>\d+))?    > /users/77            : pass
Passed 52/52 tests.
```

Comment: I'm confused, are you trying to literally reverse the Regex itself, trying to find a Regex that matches your Regex, or trying to create a string that your Regex matches?

Comment: If Django does it, couldn't you look at their source?

Comment: @SimpleCoder: I thought the very first sentence said it all: I'm trying to find a string that my regex matches.

Comment: @Svish: I *can* and I did... but couldn't make much sense of it :p Plus, they don't support `|` or look-arounds. And I doubt if they support negative character sets, but I haven't checked.

Comment: @Ralph: Well from title, `Algorithm for reversing a regex`, I thought you wanted to reverse the order of the tokens in your regex.

Comment: @SimpleCoder: Maybe you should read more than just the title :) What would be the point of reversing the order of the tokens?

Comment: @Ralph: I did read your entire post; hence my confusion.

Comment: You might do better by converting the regex to a finite state model. You then generate a string by doing a walk through the state model.

Comment: @Steve314: Is a finite state model the same as a finite state machine? I only have minimal experience with those. You think I should walk through the pattern character-by-character and branch as necessary?

Comment: @Ralph: If I'm not mistaken, a finite state machine executes a finite state model, but I think they are used more or less interchangeably.

Comment: Django seems to take that character-by-character approach. The thing I don't like about it is that it needs a lot of memory... you can't make decisions based on a single character. A named capture `(?<name>` is actually quite a few characters. Still... it might be better than what I have.

Comment: @Ralph - yes, and in a sense you're already walking the state model - only you haven't constructed that state model as a simple data structure in advance. Each of those regex strings you derive is (1) a regex for the rest of the string, and (2) the description of a state. So one approach to this requires you solve the same problem that you already need to solve - only doing it while constructing an explicit state model (by exploring every reachable state, deriving every reachable tail regex). That's why it's a comment - it's not really an answer. But there are ready-made solutions out there.

Comment: @Ralph - to handle those quantifiers, since your current approach doesn't have a memory, build the memory into the way you derive your tail-regex strings / state descriptions. If a regex specifies n-to-m repeats of x, when you accept an x, the new state will normally accept (n-1)-to-(m-1) repeats of x - but watch for counts reaching zero.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using Regex to generate Strings rather than match them](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22115/using-regex-to-generate-strings-rather-than-match-them)

Comment: Before we start closing this question as a dupe.... note that I'm looking for a solution in C#, not Java. One that supports as much of the .NET regex syntax as possible, and it should generate the shortest possible URL-safe string (or close to).

Comment: I voted to close BECAUSE YOU DID NOT ASK A QUESTION.  You have a very interesting project there.  Now, what is your question? What do you want help with?

Comment: @abelenky: Oops.. I think with all the edits I removed the actual question. The question was "are there are any pre-made libraries that do this?"... I added that back in.

Answer (score 4):

see for example [Using Regex to generate Strings rather than match them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22115/using-regex-to-generate-strings-rather-than-match-them)

also you can take a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deterministic_finite-state_machine especially at "Accept and Generate modes" section.

as others noted you will need to create a DFA from your regular expression and then generate your strings using this DFA.

to convert your regular expression to DFA, generate NFA first (see for example http://lambda.uta.edu/cse5317/spring01/notes/node9.html) and then convert NFA to DFA.

the easiest way i see is to use a parser generator program for that. i do not think django does this.

hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

*"Are there any pre-made C# libraries that do this?"*

**NO**

(I expect this will be accepted as the answer momentarily)

Comment: Lol...that's a bit of a cocky response, and not entirely true :P My library will be released in about 30 minutes. =)