# Generate test data from a REGEX

Tags: c#, regex, random

Folks,

Does anyone know of a dll or .net code that will generate test data from a REGEX?

I am aware of [The Regular Expression Generator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa833197(VS.90).aspx) and the solutions offered in the stackoverflow question  [Using Regex to generate Strings rather than match them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22115/using-regex-to-generate-strings-rather-than-match-them).

Unfortunately, I am writing in C#, and I need to generate the test data at run time.

I have also tried [Rex](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/rex/), but it blows an error when I try to load it on a virtual machine.

Any help would be appreciated.

Regards,

Brett Nieland

Comment: I think generating test data from a REGEX is a great idea.  I was wondering if you learned any new info on this subject?

Comment: Not really.  @NikosBaxevanis below has a good link...

Answer (score 2):

There is a Microsoft reasearch tool called Rex that explores .NET regexes and generates members efficiently. http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/rex/

As I have seen, you already tried Rex: Maybe the blog [post](http://www.kodefuguru.com/post/2010/05/03/Generate-Matches-for-Regular-Expressions-Using-Rex.aspx) from Chris Eargle helps you then.

Comment: Thanks, that article is what initially led me to REX!  I sure wish they would release the source code...

Answer (score 0):

You may also want to look at project [Fare](https://github.com/moodmosaic/Fare). See the answer at this question: [convert nfa to dfa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5841454/convert-nfa-to-dfa/8240209#8240209)