# Enumerate Possible Matches of Regular Expression in Java

Tags: java, regex, enumeration

I want to enumerate all the possible values of a finite regular expression in Java for testing purposes.

For some context, I have a regular expression that I'm using to match allowable color values in words. Here's a shortened version of it as an example:

```
(white|black)|((light|dark) )?(red|green|blue|gray)
```

I wanted to create a unit test that would enumerate all these values and pass each of them to my utility class which produces a `Color` object from these, that way if I change the regular expression, my unit tests will fail if an error occurs (i.e. the new color value is unsupported).

I know enumeration is possible, of course ([see this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6643730/producing-all-possible-matches-of-a-regular-expression)), but is there an existing library for Java which will enumerate all the possible matches for a regex?

**Edit:** I've implemented a library that does this. See my answer below for links.

Comment: Do you want *all* of the infinite number of possible matches (with varying amounts of whitespace), or just some finite number of them?

Comment: You say `finite regular expression` by which I suppose you mean `regular expression that describes a finite language`. Note that in that case, your regular expressions isn't "finite". It contains a `+`.

Comment: @m.buettner Ah, that it does. I guess I'll have to remove the plus then. Oh well, I didn't like it anyway.

Comment: Reopening this question. The linked duplicate was for _random_ match generation, not generation of all possible matches.

Comment: Note your library doesn't need to be in Java.  You can use any technology to generate your test cases then just simply save them to a `good.txt` file.

Comment: @Brian well, I suppose if you run it long enough...

Comment: @owlstead Ha, well how do I know when it's done? :P

Comment: For the record, I'm using `matches`, so I don't need the `^$`.

Comment: @djechlin The problem with using other technologies is then that technology has to be installed on all dev machines. I'd rather have a Java solution which I can add as a dependency to my JUnit tests that can generate it dynamically. Also, putting all of them into a text file isn't useful since the reason I want it is for dynamic unit tests based on the possible values of the regex. Using a text file makes everything defined statically.

Comment: you need something like this: http://regldg.com/docs/index.php but I have not seen a java impl

Comment: @maasg That's exactly what I need. If only it were Java.

Comment: See also [Generate all valid values for a regular expression](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15950113/generate-all-valid-values-for-a-regular-expression) and [Using Regex to generate Strings rather than match them](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22115/using-regex-to-generate-strings-rather-than-match-them)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are right, didn't find such a tool online as well 
but you can try [Xeger](http://code.google.com/p/xeger/) from google

it can create a random matching string from a regexp, and with some code tweaking might do what you want.
generation a random match:

```
String regex = "[ab]{4,6}c";
Xeger generator = new Xeger(regex);
String result = generator.generate();
assert result.matches(regex);
```

Xeger code is very simple, it consists of 2 files which contain 5 methods between them..
it uses dk.brics.automaton to conver the regex to an automaton, then goes over the automaton transitions making random choices in every node.

the main function is generate:

```
   private void generate(StringBuilder builder, State state) {
    List<Transition> transitions = state.getSortedTransitions(true);
    if (transitions.size() == 0) {
        assert state.isAccept();
        return;
    }
    int nroptions = state.isAccept() ? transitions.size() : transitions.size() - 1;
    int option = XegerUtils.getRandomInt(0, nroptions, random);
    if (state.isAccept() && option == 0) {          // 0 is considered stop
        return;
    }
    // Moving on to next transition
    Transition transition = transitions.get(option - (state.isAccept() ? 1 : 0));
    appendChoice(builder, transition);
    generate(builder, transition.getDest());
}
```

you can see that in order to change it so you get all possible matches, you need to iterate over all possible combinations in every possible node (like incrementing a multi digit counter)
you will need a hash to prevent loops, but that shouldn't take more than 5 senconds to code..

i would also suggest first checking that the regex is actually finate, by checking that it doesn't have *,+ and other symbols that make this action impossible (just to make this a complete tool for reuse)...

Comment: +1, this is pretty much what I was expecting I'd have to do. I've been looking into `dk.brics.automaton` and its usage in Xeger. Luckily, `dk.brics.automaton` is BSD-licensed. Perhaps I can write up an open source library for this since it seems like no one else has implemented this (at least not in open source).

Comment: On your finite comment, I should be good with just unclosed quantifiers, including greedy, reluctant, and possessive `*`, `+`, and `{n,}`. I'm pretty sure those are the only ones that can result in unbounded repetition.

Answer (score 1):

For future browsers coming to this question, I wrote a library that uses [dk.brics.automaton](http://www.brics.dk/automaton/) using a similar approach to [Xeger](https://github.com/bluezio/xeger) from the accepted answer and published it. You can find it:

- On [GitHub](https://github.com/bsaltz/greex)
- On [the project site](http://greex.navigamez.com/)
- In [Maven Central](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.navigamez/greex/)

To add it as a dependency:

#### Maven

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.navigamez</groupId>
    <artifactId>greex</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

#### Gradle

```
compile 'com.navigamez:greex:1.0'
```

#### Sample Code

Using this question as an example:

```
GreexGenerator generator = new GreexGenerator("(white|black)|((light|dark) )?(red|green|blue|gray)");
List<String> matches = generator.generateAll();
System.out.println(matches.size()); // "14"
```