# Generate all valid values for a regular expression

Tags: java, regex, generator

I know by using Xeger, we can get a random value for a specified pattern.

```
String regex = "[0-9]{2}"; 
Xeger generator = new Xeger(regex);
String result = generator.generate();
```

I want to know is there a way to return all of the valid strings for the specified regex. For example, for pattern: `[0-9]{2}`, we can get all of the values from `00` to `99`.

Thanks

Edit:

Here we don't consider the infinite outputs like + and *; how can we get all values for a finite regex?

Last edit:

Thanks everyone! Finally I don't consider all the possible values as there may be thousands. I limit a specific number as the number of values to reduce the amount.

Comment: +1 for question but for most regular expressions number of matching strings is unlimited. For example `[0-9]+`

Comment: This can only work for regexes that only admit finite-length inputs. For example, the `*` and `+` operators are out. Presumably you're OK with this?

Comment: @NPE You don't have to generate infinitely many values to return a generator that constructs each possible result, throws it out, constructs the next, etc. Think python generators :)

Comment: Even without that limitation, you'll run into trouble pretty darn quickly. Storing all possible strings for `\w{10}` (if `\w` is defined as only ASCII letters/digits/underscore) will require about 43 Petabytes of storage. Enjoy.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Enumerate Possible Matches of Regular Expression in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13688778/enumerate-possible-matches-of-regular-expression-in-java)

Comment: Can you please upvote the useful answers, and accept the best one? I see that you still have to accept an answer in your other month-long answer... it's not required, but as you can see SO is very limited for low-reputation users, and not everyone of us has a >1000 rep score

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since a regexp is defined by a finite state machine, I wondered if there was something out there able to automatically reason on such machines and that was a good fit to be repurposed for this work... and [clojure.core.logic delivered](https://gist.github.com/Pet3ris/1676242)

So, I looked at this [definition of the regexp grammar](http://www.cs.sfu.ca/~cameron/Teaching/384/99-3/regexp-plg.html) (unfortunately, it lacks the {} quantifiers, but they should be pretty easy to add to my code) adapted it to the java escapes, and worked out this 110 lines long clojure program:

```
(ns regexp-unfolder.core
  (:require [instaparse.core :as insta])
  (:require [clojure.core.logic :as l])
  (:require [clojure.set :refer [union difference]])
  (:gen-class :methods [#^{:static true} [unfold [String] clojure.lang.LazySeq]])
)

(def parse-regexp (insta/parser 
             "re = union | simple-re?
             union = re '|' simple-re
             simple-re = concat | base-re
             concat = simple-re base-re
             base-re = elementary-re | star | plus
             star = elementary-re '*'
             plus = elementary-re '+'
             elementary-re = group | char | '$' | any | set
             any = '.'
             group = '(' re ')'
             set = positive-set | negative-set
             positive-set = '['  set-items ']'
             negative-set = '[^' set-items ']'
             set-items = set-item*
             set-item = range | char
             range = char '-' char
             char = #'[^\\\\\\-\\[\\]]|\\.'" ))

(def printables (set (map char (range 32 127))))

(declare fns handle-first)

(defn handle-tree [q qto [ type & nodes]]
  (if (nil? nodes)
    [[q [""] qto]]
    ((fns type handle-first) q qto nodes)))

(defn star [q qto node &]
  (cons [q [""] qto]
         (handle-tree q q (first node))))

(defn plus [q qto node &] 
  (concat (handle-tree q qto (first node))
          (handle-tree qto qto (first node))))

(defn any-char [q qto & _] [[q (vec printables) qto]] )

(defn char-range [[c1 _ c2]]
  (let [extract-char (comp int first seq second)]
    (set (map char (range (extract-char c1) (inc (extract-char c2)))))))

(defn items [nodes]
  (union (mapcat
    (fn [[_ [type & ns]]]
      (if (= type :char)
        #{(first ns)}        
        (char-range ns)))
    (rest (second nodes)))))

(defn handle-set [q qto node &] [[q (vec (items node)) qto]])

(defn handle-negset [q qto node &] [[q (vec (difference printables (items node))) qto]])

(defn handle-range [q qto & nodes] [[q (vec (char-range nodes)) qto]])

(defn handle-char [q qto node &] [[q (vec node) qto]] )

(defn handle-concat [q qto nodes] 
  (let [syms (for [x  (rest nodes)] (gensym q))]
    (mapcat handle-tree  (cons q syms) (concat syms [qto] ) nodes)
  ))

(defn handle-first [q qto [node & _]] (handle-tree q qto node))

(def fns {:concat handle-concat, :star star, :plus plus, :any any-char, :positive-set handle-set, :negative-set handle-negset, :char handle-char})

(l/defne transition-membero
  [state trans newstate otransition]
  ([_ _ _ [state trans-set newstate]]
     (l/membero trans trans-set)))

(defn transitiono [state trans newstate transitions]
  (l/conde
   [(l/fresh [f] 
             (l/firsto transitions f)
             (transition-membero state trans newstate f))]
   [(l/fresh [r]
             (l/resto transitions r)
             (transitiono state trans newstate r))])
  )

(declare transitions)

;; Recognize a regexp finite state machine encoded in triplets [state, transition, next-state], adapted from a snippet made by Peteris Erins

(defn recognizeo
  ([input]
     (recognizeo 'q0 input))
  ([q input]
     (l/matche [input] ; start pattern matching on the input
        (['("")]
           (l/== q 'ok)) ; accept the empty string if we are in an accepting state
        ([[i . nput]]
           (l/fresh [qto]
                  (transitiono q i qto transitions) ; assert it must be what we transition to qto from q with input symbol i
                  (recognizeo qto nput)))))) ; recognize the remainder


(defn -unfold [regex] 
  (def transitions 
    (handle-tree 'q0 'ok (parse-regexp regex)))
  (map (partial apply str) (l/run* [q] (recognizeo q))))
```

Being written with core.logic, it should be fairly easy to adapt it to work also as a regexp matcher

I limited the printables characters from 32 to 126 ascii, otherwise it'd be too cumbersome to deal with regexps such as `[^c]`, but you can extend it quite easily... also, I haven't implemented yet unions, optional patterns, and the \w, \s, etc. escapes for character classes

This is the biggest thing I wrote in clojure up to now, but the basics seems to be covered just fine... some examples:

```
regexp-unfolder.core=> (-unfold "ba[rz]")
("bar" "baz")
regexp-unfolder.core=> (-unfold "[a-z3-7]")
("a" "b" "c" "d" "e" "f" "g" "h" "i" "j" "k" "l" "m" "n" "o" "p" "q" "r" "s" "t" "u" "v" "w" "x" "y" "z" "3" "4" "5" "6" "7")
regexp-unfolder.core=> (-unfold "[a-z3-7][01]")
("a0" "a1" "b0" "b1" "c0" "c1" "d0" "d1" "e0" "e1" "f0" "f1" "g0" "g1" "h0" "h1" "i0" "i1" "j0" "j1" "k0" "k1" "l0" "l1" "m0" "m1" "n0" "n1" "o0" "o1" "p0" "p1" "q0" "q1" "r0" "r1" "s0" "s1" "t0" "t1" "u0" "u1" "v0" "v1" "w0" "w1" "x0" "x1" "y0" "y1" "z0" "z1" "30" "31" "40" "41" "50" "51" "60" "70" "61" "71")
regexp-unfolder.core=> (-unfold "[^A-z]")
(" " "@" "!" "\"" "#" "$" "%" "&" "'" "(" ")" "*" "+" "," "-" "." "/" "0" "1" "2" "3" "4" "5" "6" "7" "8" "9" ":" ";" "{" "<" "|" "=" "}" ">" "~" "?")
regexp-unfolder.core=> (take 20 (-unfold "[abc]*"))
("" "a" "b" "c" "aa" "ab" "ac" "ba" "ca" "aaa" "bb" "cb" "aab" "bc" "cc" "aac" "aba" "aca" "baa" "caa")
regexp-unfolder.core=> (take 20 (-unfold "a+b+"))
("ab" "aab" "abb" "abbb" "aaab" "abbbb" "aabb" "abbbbb" "abbbbbb" "aabbb" "abbbbbbb" "abbbbbbbb" "aaaab" "aabbbb" "aaabb" "abbbbbbbbb" "abbbbbbbbbb" "aabbbbb" "abbbbbbbbbbb" "abbbbbbbbbbbb")
```

Since I started this way, I implemented also infinite outputs :)

If someone is interested, I [uploaded it here](https://launchpad.net/regexp-unfolder)

and obviously, here's an example of how to invoke `unfold` from plain old Java:

```
import static regexp_unfolder.core.unfold;

public class UnfolderExample{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        Iterable<String> strings = unfold("a+b+");
        for (String s : strings){
            System.out.println(s);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Here is am open-source generator [RegLdg](http://regldg.com), written in `C` language -  the regular expression grammar language dictionary generator.

I believe it will be not very difficult to make a Java port of this program.

Comment: I downloaded the RegLdg but it gives me error while I hit the make all command:
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:21: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 1

Answer (score 2):

Finding all matches is very similar to finding a random match. Below is a simple modification of the logic that generates random matches on [www.debuggex.com](http://www.debuggex.com), assuming you already have a parse tree.

The idea is that for every subtree, you return a list of all possible generated strings, given a string that was generated by all previous nodes in your parse tree.

```
AltTree.all = (prefix) ->
    rets = []
    for child in children
        rets.extend(child.all(prefix))

ConcatTree.all = (prefix) ->
    prefixes = [prefix]
    for child in children
        newPrefixes = []
        for p in prefixes
            newPrefixes.extend(child.all(p))
        prefixes = newPrefixes
    return prefixes

RepeatTree.all = (prefix) ->
    prefixes = [prefix]
    rets = []
    for i up to max
        newPrefixes = []
        for p in prefixes
            newPrefixes.extend(onlyChild.all(p))
        prefixes = newPrefixes
        if i >= min
            rets.extend(prefixes)
    return rets

CharsetTree.all = (prefix) ->
    rets = []
    for char in allValidChars():
        rets.push(prefix + char)
    return rets
```

The rest of the trees are left as exercises (most notably the literal tree).

Note that there are intentionally no optimizations for the sake of clarity. Calling `myTree.all('')` will generate a list such that every valid matching string appears once **for every path that generates this string**. You will probably want to add deduplication and get rid of the excessive copying.

I should also add that this will only work for regular expressions that have a *small* number of total matching strings. This is because all of the strings are being stored. If you want to get around this limitation, you can `yield`ify this algorithm. You will need to maintain a stack (think of it as being a bread crumb trail) of where you are in the tree. When a new string is asked for, you will create it from the path you travelled, and then update the path.

Answer (score 0):

A trivial implementation of such algorithm is simply:

```
def generate_matching(pattern):
    alphabets = [...]
    l = 1
    while True:
        # generate all Cartesian product of the alphabets of length `l`
        for s in itertools.product(alphabets, repeat=l):
            s = "".join(s)
            if pattern.match(s):
                print s
        l += 1
```

Comment: Isn't the hard part of this generating the `alphabets` in such a way that you're not throwing away over 99.9% of the work you're doing?  Doesn't this basically just generate every possible string and compare it to the regex?