# Output all regex permutations?

Tags: regex

Is there a site or way to output all of the permutations of a regex pattern?

I made a simple pattern here with desired output from this 'app':

https://regex101.com/r/lE2tS8/2

or see below:

```
(?<TERM>(Big |Small )(Brown |Green |Red )(Ball|Box))
```

- Big Brown Ball
- Big Green Ball
- Big Red Ball
- Small Brown Ball
- Small Green Ball
- Small Red Ball
- Big Brown Box
- Big Green Box
- Big Red Box
- Small Brown Box
- Small Green Box
- Small Red Box

Comment: but it could be infinite..

Comment: It can not be achieved with just regex. You'd need _some_ language to compute the logic.

Comment: Also, look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15950113/generate-all-valid-values-for-a-regular-expression

Comment: @ergonaut: infinite only if you have non finite quantifiers: `*`, `+`, `{a,}` or recursions, but that isn't the case in this example.

Comment: Since a regex is really a mini program, this is a [halting problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem) and as such is only open to being modeled for general regex's. This specific regex is more amenable to analysis. Have you tried something like [this?](http://hackingoff.com/compilers/regular-expression-to-nfa-dfa)