# Generate a String for a given size

Tags: java, string, random, stringbuilder

How can I generate a String of a given size?

```
int someLimit = GlobalLimits.BULK_SIZE;
```

I want 3 Strings which satisfy the below conditions.

### - RandomStr.length < someLimit.length

### - RandomStr.length = someLimit.length

### - RandomStr.length > someLimit.length

This is what I have tried so far.

```
private String getLowerRandomString(int upto){
  StringBuilder sBuilder = new StringBuilder();
  for (int i = 0; i < upto; i++){
    sBuilder.append("A");
  }

  return sBuilder.toString();
}
```

**The problem what I see is**, if my limit = 10000, it still loop up-to 9999 which is unnecessary. Share if you know a better approach than this. Thank you.

---

FYI:
I was writing a unit test for a simple helper method.

```
public boolean isBulk(String text){
 int bulkLimit = ImportToolkit.getSizeLimit();
 if (text != null && text.length() > bulkLimit){
  return true;
 }
 return false;
}
```

So, I want to pass different sizes of strings as parameters to this method and want to assert whether it gives me expected results.

Comment: Why do you think the loop is unnecessary? If you need to create a string of 10,000 characters then there's going to be a loop somewhere - if it isn't in your own code, the loop is going to be in some string utils library that you call. There's no way to make this "more efficient" without having a loop *somewhere*. Also, computers do this really fast, so why are you worrying about the loop? Is there a real performance problem or are you just worrying without really knowing that there is a problem?

Comment: I actually don't have any idea about that limit. It could be even more than 10k. So I just thought, whether if there might be a better approach than this. BTW; this is for a unit testing purpose. :)

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/43496/2193767

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What about using apache commons? It has a RandomStringUtils class that provides exactly the functionality you're looking for, but in the end it loops too...

```
org.apache.commons.lang3.RandomStringUtils#randomAlphanumeric(int count)
```

From JavaDoc

```
Creates a random string whose length is the number of characters specified.

Characters will be chosen from the set of alpha-numeric characters.

Parameters:
    count - the length of random string to create
Returns:
    the random string
```

If it doesn't need to be random there is another, cheaper method in Stringutils:

```
org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils#repeat(char, int)
```

But in the end it too loops...

From JavaDoc

```
Returns padding using the specified delimiter repeated to a given length.

 StringUtils.repeat('e', 0)  = ""
 StringUtils.repeat('e', 3)  = "eee"
 StringUtils.repeat('e', -2) = ""


Note: this method doesn't not support padding with Unicode Supplementary Characters as they require a pair of chars to be represented. If you are needing to support full I18N of your applications consider using repeat(String, int) instead.

Parameters:
    ch - character to repeat
    repeat - number of times to repeat char, negative treated as zero
Returns:
    String with repeated character
See Also:
    repeat(String, int)
```

Comment: You gotta love commons!

Answer (score 2):

If you're only concerned about the string's length, you can just do this:

```
String str = new String(new char[SIZE]);
```

This is useful, for example, when you want to test if a given method fails when it is given a string of a specific length.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at Xeger library [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22115/using-regex-to-generate-strings-rather-than-match-them) . Your code would go like this.

```
    public static void main(String[] args){


 String regex="([0-9]{100})";     
    System.out.println(new Xeger(regex).generate());

}
```

Output :- `5262521775458685393102235626265923114201782357574146361524512101753254114567366125627554628148696482`

You can change 100 or 1000 according to your need.

Jar Location [here](http://www.antepedia.com/detail/p/xeger.html).

-Sid

Answer (score 0):

If you only concern about the string length, Do a mathematical operation that result a big value. Convert that result value as string and perform your validation. If you do not want numeric then, instead of appending single string 'a' to stringBuilder. Append a big string and in your for loop increment based on the length of the string that you append to string builder.

Answer (score 0):

Use Random to generate a number less than Limit and greater than limit and pass to function to generate a string of that length

```
       lowerLimit= 0 + (int)(Math.random() * maximum); 
       higherLimit= minimum + (int)(Math.random() * maximum);
       smallerString= getLowerRandomString(lowerLimit);
       greaterString= getLowerRandomString(higherLimit);
```

For help on limiting random number, please check this post.[How do I generate random integers within a specific range in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/363681/generating-random-integers-in-a-specific-range)

Answer (score 0):

Please refer the [**link**](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Development-Class/Generatesasecurerandomwordwiththegivenlengthconsistingofuppercaseandlowercaselettersandnumbers.htm) which has the secure way to create random string for any specified length. I have used it in my project and it worked fine.