# How to generate a random String from a Regex?

Tags: java, regex

am currently trying to generate a string that matches a given regex, I've been working on this for few days without good solution. I tried using the Generex library which works find until i put in some more complicated regex like this

`"^((\w+([-+.]\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*)\s*[;]{0,1}\s*)+$"`

or

`"(?:(NGN|USA|TWN|IND|VN)\h*,?\h*(?!.*\1))+"`,

this have proven to be the biggest issue I've encountered in Software Engineering Field.

The question is how can i generate random matching String from Regex correctly.

NOTE: [Using Regex to generate Strings rather than match them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22115/using-regex-to-generate-strings-rather-than-match-them) doesn't work for me, Generex works with more simpler format of regex rather than the complicated onces, the two examples above is kinda complicated, but those regex isn't decided by me, so there is no way i can modify it.

Comment: I see a question mark but no question.

Comment: Whats the question exactly?

Comment: you mean in the regex ?

Comment: @BalwinderSingh i will edit the question to make it more clearer, the question is how can i generate a string from regex correctly.

Comment: @shmosel *I see a question mark* I see three

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using Regex to generate Strings rather than match them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22115/using-regex-to-generate-strings-rather-than-match-them)

Comment: @KeerthanaPrabhakaran it isn't really a duplicate, the suggession from that question doesn't work for me, They did advise using Xeger/Generex

Comment: Might be a good fit for CodeGolf like here: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/156315/373 - maybe not welcomed, if you don't have a solution, just ask on meta. I would try the usual way: Didivide and impera. Solve subexpressions, than bigger expressions. Maybe a combination of analisis and brute forcing?

Comment: Have you looked at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22115/using-regex-to-generate-strings-rather-than-match-them? Why Generex/Xeger isn't working for you?

Comment: yes, Generex works with more simpler format of regex rather than the complicated onces, the two examples above is kinda complicated, but those regex isn't decided by me, so there is no way i can modify it

Comment: Xeger works for me with the regular expressions you've provided

Comment: @G i tried using it, but it's generation some characters that isn't recognize and after validating with my PatternMatcher component return false